# how to write UNPIVOT correctly?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unpivot

a have a table "research" with columns "ID", "code1", "code2", "soc0", "soc1" ... "socn"
where n = 40.

The values of cells are not important at the moment as I need to get a list of "soc" columns like:

```
soc0  
soc1   
....  
soc40
```

Can you please help me to write unpivot query?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: If you want just the columns' names, then why do you want to use the `UNPIVOT` table operator for this? Why not reading these columns' names directly from `information_schema.columns`??

Comment: to FreshPrince - I made my homework, all topics describe how to pivot the values of tables. But as i sad i need only columns' names for my further actions.
to Mahmoud - I had to tasks to get the same result. One of them was with information_schema.columns and I made it. Another task was to get result using unpivot function. That is why i am asking for help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `UNPIVOT` function to get this.

The basic syntax is:

```
select *
from research
unpivot
(
  value
  for col in (soc0, soc1, soc40)
) un;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5d6fc/7)

But you will have to type out all of the column names that you want to unpivot. If you do not want to type of all of the column names, then you can use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @colsUnpivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsUnpivot = stuff((select ','+quotename(C.column_name)
         from information_schema.columns as C
         where C.table_name = 'research' and
               C.column_name like 'soc%'
         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

set @query 
  = 'select id, col, value
     from research
     unpivot
     (
        value
        for col in ('+ @colsunpivot +')
     ) u'

exec(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5d6fc/6)

But if you just want a list of the column names, then you can query this directly without the unpivot:

```
select C.table_name, C.column_name
from information_schema.columns c
where C.table_name = 'research' and
  C.column_name like 'soc%'
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5d6fc/9)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select  unpvt.value
from research c
unpivot ( 
 value 
 for attribute in (Colsoc0,Colsoc1,Colsoc2,..,Colsocn)
) unpvt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  *
from    research
unpivot (
        CodeValue for CodeName in (code0, code1, code2)
        ) sub
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dc2f9/1/0)